# Can't select elements of specific type

Tags: xml, xpath

Using this [online XPath tester](http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/xml-xpath-tester.html) I tried extracting all `<subject>` elements from following XML document.

```
<recordData>
<srw_dc:dc xmlns:srw_dc="info:srw/schema/1/dc-schema" xmlns="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="info:srw/schema/1/dc-schema http://www.loc.gov/standards/sru/resources/dc-schema.xsd">
<title>Classical philosophy : a contemporary introduction</title>
<creator>Shields, Christopher John (NO-TrBIB)x99040447</creator>
<type>text</type>
<publisher>London Routledge</publisher>
<date>2003</date>
<language>eng</language>
<subject>Gresk oldtid</subject>
<subject>Filosofi</subject>
<subject>Antikken</subject>
<subject>filosofi</subject>
<subject>antikken</subject>
<relation/>
<identifier>http://content.bibsys.no/content/?type=descr_publ_brief&amp;isbn=0415233976</identifier>
<identifier>http://content.bibsys.no/content/?type=descr_publ_full&amp;isbn=0415233976</identifier>
<identifier>http://content.bibsys.no/content/?type=toc&amp;isbn=0415233976</identifier>
<identifier>URN:ISBN:0415233976</identifier>
<identifier>URN:ISBN:0415233984</identifier>
</srw_dc:dc>
</recordData>
```

I can extract **all** inner elements and **all** text content of the inner elements with the following two XPath expressions: `*/*/*`, `*/*/*/text()`.

But I can't just select ones of a specific type: `*/*/subject`, `*/*/subject/text()`.

Why is that?

Comment: What language are you using to parse the xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the XML document has a *default namespace*:

```
xmlns="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
```

An XPath expression like `*/*/subject` looks for elements that are called "subject" and are in *no* namespace. Here are two ways to solve the problem:

- change the XPath expression to `/*/*/*[local-name() = 'subject']` or even `//*[local-name() = 'subject']` if the level of nesting actually does not matter
- if you use an online XPath tester only for, well, testing purposes (that's the only thing you should use them for) look for an XPath library in your programming language that can handle namespaces. Then register the namespace URI together with a prefix and replace `subject` with `prefix:subject`. This is the proper way to solve the problem.